# Renv is restarting my pc prompting a blue screen when i try to remove renv folder

Tags: r, renv

I created a project on Rstudio and and tried to delete all the folders created by the project. I also created an renv (r virtual enviroment) and when I tried to delete that folder my system is prompting a blue windows screen. I tried to `renv::deactivate()` but it is not working

Comment: I can think of nothing in R that would trigger an operating system to freeze or hang up. While it's feasible to write C++ code that can cause R to crash, perhaps even the RStudio IDE (untested, unproven), I find it really hard to believe that any operating system would allow that problem to affect anything other than the app. (And `renv` is only R-code, nothing in C/C++. I think a plausible reason is that your filesystem is corrupt in or around the project directory, or your hard drive has bad sectors. Both of those could cause OS issues.

Comment: BTW, `renv` is not about "virtual" environments, it is for R *"**r**eproducible **env**ironments"* (taken from `renv`s [github readme](https://github.com/rstudio/renv)). It is similar in name and purpose to python's `venv`, which *does* define itself as a virtual environment (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) ... so perhaps this is just dancing around words.

Comment: I just managed to delete the folder by going to OneDrive website and deleting from the cloud. Weird

Comment: It sounds like a onedrive problem ...